# pass Field Name as parameter in store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

[image: My Search Box]

I Want To search On Word(Text Box) in Selected Combo Box Item(field in DataBase) ,
my Store procedure is :

```
USE [QueueDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_SelectDriver_ByNameAndField]    Script Date: 09/07/2012 17:20:24 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SelectDriver_ByNameAndField]
@Word nvarchar(100),
@Field nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
select * from Driver where @Field like + N'%' + @Word + '%'
END
```

it does not work , what way you suggest to do this search method ?

Comment: How do you think Sql Server would precompile a query plan for this? I'd suggest using dynamic sql. What will be calling the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azize del,

ComboBox hamishe baiangare LookUp ast ke hamanande Table eist ke 2 sotoune Id va Describer darad. Agar gharar ast ke meghdare entekhabie ComboBox be StoredProcedure ferestade beshe, pishnahad mikonam az Id e Bind shode be SelectedValue e ComboBox estefade beshe. Nvarchar ro be SP ferestadan kare dorosti nist.

Dear Sir/Madam,

ComboBox is always a replacement for LookUp in Information Systems that is like a Table that has only two columns, Id and Describer. If you're about to send the SelectedValue of ComboBox to your StoredProcedure, I suggest to send the bound value of SelectedValue as an integer to it. Then you have many options to write your query. Sending a LookUp value by using Nvarchar might have many side effects in the future of your application (it has many issues with collation in comparison).

Cheers

Change Code to this:

```
USE [QueueDB]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_SelectDriver_ByNameAndField]    Script Date: 09/07/2012 17:20:24 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SelectDriver_ByNameAndField]  (
    @Word   Nvarchar(100)
,   @Field  TinyInt
)   As  Begin

    Select *
        From    Driver
        Where   Case    When    @Field      =   1
                And Column1     Like + N'%' + @Word + '%'
                Then    1
                When    @Field      =   2
                And Column2     Like + N'%' + @Word + '%'
                Then    1
                When    @Field      =   3
                And Column3     Like + N'%' + @Word + '%'
                Then    1
                Else    0
            End =   1
    ;

    Return  0;

END
```

Also you can use another way:

```
USE [QueueDB]
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SelectDriver_ByNameAndField]  (
    @Word   Nvarchar(100)
,   @Field  TinyInt
)   As  Begin

    Declare @Command    Nvarchar(Max);

    Select  @Command    =   N'
    Select *
        From    Driver
        Where   '
    +   Case    When    @Field      =   1
                Then    'Column1'
                When    @Field      =   2
                Then    'Column2'
                When    @Field      =   3
                Then    'Column3'
                Else    'DefaultColumn'
            End
    +   N'  Like + N''%'
    +   @Word
    +   N'%'''
    ;

    Execute (@Command);

    Return  0;

END
```

Comment: @flem Questioner is Iranian and all of us having lots of problems with learning english. Please be patient, I'll add an english comment too. Just for you. ;) Cheers

Comment: thank you mohammad ,the solution was so useful and helped me , thanks in advance, Mamnoon ;)

Comment: Chakerim! Cheers bro, just vote up my comment if you want (and if you can, there is no must!). ;)

Comment: works good but why each rows in database come twice in result ?

Comment: In different situations, it depends on data, input values and what you're coding. So I think it would be better to add the Case statement as a column to your query result and check the output value when goes to one and when is zero.

Comment: select statement have problem ! i select data from two table and use "select tbl1.field ,tbl2.field from tbl1,tbl2" Because of this rows come twice ! how can i solve it ?

Comment: I think you have problem with the query. Post your query to see what is it. As I see you used two tables with names tbl1 and tbl2. There might be a join that cause this problem. It's a logical issue not technical.

Comment: problem has been solved , i have forgotten to place "where" in my select command

Answer (score 2):

You can't use dynamic column names in SQL.

In order to achieve what you want, you will need to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). The linked article has a comprehensive discussion about this subject.

Comment: if  it is not possible how can i do ? write store procedure for each Item in combo box?

Comment: You could do that, or you could construct the query and pass it to `sp_executeSql`, or, if you use the ADO.Net `command` class it will do it for you. However, that assumes something about your client. I suggest you investigate the link posted by Oded. The rest of the site is very informative too.